# What is wrong with the following code that uses virtual functions?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use and learn virtual functions, but my first attempt is a mess. The code is pretty straightforward.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class milk
{
    string strname; // The string that hold the product name

public:
    milk(string namestr):strname(namestr) // The default constructor
    {}

    string getname()
    {
        return strname; // The only name return function
    }

    virtual void taste()
    {
        cout << "I am sweet and liquid";
    }

};

class chocolate:public milk
{
public:
    chocolate(string pname):milk(pname)
    {}

    virtual void taste()
    {
        cout << "I am sweet and solid";
    }
};

class butter:public milk
{
public:
    butter(string cname):milk(cname)
    {}

    virtual const void taste()
    {
        cout << "I am sour and solid";
    }
};

int main()
{
    chocolate choc("KitKat");
    cout << "Hi!!, I am" << choc.getname() << choc.taste(); // The error is here
    butter butt("Amul");
    cout << "Hi!! I am " << butt.getname() << butt.taste(); // Also here
    cin.get();
}
```

There, there were the errors. Should I pass the virtual functions as pointers or what is it?

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? Also, your inheritance model is a little strange, but that's fine.

Comment: You sure this code compiled? You need to `#include <string>` and not `<string.h>`; former is a C++ header while the latter is a C header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getname` and `taste` functions are declared to return `void`, so you can't call them in the middle of a `cout` statement. Perhaps you may have meant to have them return strings.

Comment: Thanks Guys, that was awesome. And yes, I meant to havew them return strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a void method inside the *cout* statement.

Your output should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    chocolate choc("KitKat");
    cout<<"Hi!!, I am"<<choc.getname();
    choc.taste();
    butter butt("Amul");
    cout<<"Hi!! I am "<<butt.getname();
    butt.taste();
    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `main()` as:

```
  int main()
  {
    chocolate choc("KitKat");
    cout<<"Hi!!,I am"<<choc.getname();
    choc.taste();
    butter butt("Amul");
    cout<<"Hi!! I am "<<butt.getname();
    butt.taste();
    cin.get();
  }
```

You are declaring the return type of `taste()` as `void`, so you cannot use them in your `cout` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of the function *taste* in the *Butter* class is also not valid. The child class must keep the prototype of the virtual function unchanged.

```
void taste();
{
    cout << "I am sour and solid";
}
```